# Linked Lists Challenge with Pointer Next

Tags: algorithm, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, pascal

I read some articles on Linked Lists, Can, anyone, explain this example?

We have a Circular Singly Linked List that has 5 Elements. we have a pointer f that point to end of list. what is the operation of f.next.next =f.next.next.next?

In fact, I always misunderstand the pointer and next pointer in such a situation.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think it does? What have you tried so far? Did you draw a picture?

Comment: Dear @NetVipeC, it's circular...

Comment: If it is circular, how can there be an end of list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
F is the last node
f.next = node1
f.next.next = node2
f.next.next.next = node3

so f.next.next = f.next.next.next is actually node1.next = node3
```

Node 2 is still there and it still points to node3, but since no other node is pointing to it, is considered being removed from the list.

The proper thing at this point would be to delete node2 (release the memory it has allocated), but that's beyond the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Draw it on a sheet of paper with next being an arrow between 2 nodes. Look at the last node and see where it's pointing, then the answer will be trivial.

Comment: if i get a solution i didn't ask here

Comment: would you please add detail for me.?

Comment: f.next is the first node. Then f.next.next is basically n1->next so the question becomes n1.next = ? Where is the first node pointing to?

Comment: it means remove the second elements?

Comment: Yeah, you are excluding the 2nd element from the list.

Comment: please add more detail to your answer to approve it.